# Mathematica 11 ignores AllowScriptLevelChange when exporting to HTML

Tags: export, formatting, html

It seems that the front end of the version 11 does not
respect the `AllowScriptLevelChange` option when doing HTML export.

Consider the following code (call it `source_1.m`)

```
(* ::Package:: *)

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], FractionBoxOptions ->
{AllowScriptLevelChange -> False}];



(a+b)(c+d)(d+e)(f+g)/(h+i)


Export["source1.html",EvaluationNotebook[],"HTML"]
```

With Mathematica 10.3 the produced HTML looks like this

[image]

This is exactly what I want, i.e. the fractions are typeset
properly just like they look in the front end. Now repeat the
same thing with Mathematica 11

[image]

Apparently, this time the front end has completely ignored the 
`AllowScriptLevelChange` option and produced the standard (ugly)
HTML output.

Is this a bug, or should one use some other options
to change the fraction typesetting  in version 11?

I'm using Mathematica 11.0.0.0 and 10.3.1.0 on Fedora 23 (64-bit).

Comment: On Win7 V11 output look like yours from V10 plus there is this black ugly frame. p.s. I'm not sure I get why it is related to the option you are mentioning, could you explain?

Comment: @Kuba Sure. The point is that I want the fractions in the HTML output to be typeset the same way as in the frontend, i.e. $\frac{a}{b}$ instead of $a/b$. The option `AllowScriptLevelChange` does the job. However, it looks like (at least on my system) v. 11 ignores this option and still produces the $a/b$ output that I don't like.

Comment: V11, Windows here. I always get the 2d-fraction, whether or not I set that option.

Comment: Please try `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], FractionBoxOptions -> {MultilineFunction -> None}]` and report the result.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Same results as with `AllowScriptLevelChange`, i.e. works and looks on good on 10.3 but has no effect on 11.0.